# PHP Form - Having Issues

Tags: php

I've been having some serious problems getting my form to work properly. Below are first the PHP calculations (attireCalculate.php), then the PHP processing file (processAttire.php), and finally my XHTML (attireForm.php). Sorry for how long this all is, but I've been going through it over and over and over and looking all over the web to no avail. I just can't find the problem(s). Nothing happens when I click the submit button.

I should mention that I am new to programming and PHP, so it may be that whatever I am missing is really quite simple. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

attireCalculate.php

```
<?php
function message($ramHatQ, $teemoHatQ, $blitzHoodieQ, $galioHoodieQ, $datAsheQ, $graggyIceQ)
{
         $cost = sprintf("%.2lf", calculateCost($ramHatQ, $teemoHatQ, $blitzHoodieQ, $galioHoodieQ, $datAsheQ, $graggyIceQ));
         $tax = sprintf("%.2lf", calculateTax($cost));
         $total = sprintf("%.2lf", calculateTotal($cost, $tax));
         $text = "<h1>Product Summary</h1>".
                 "<h3>The cost of items selected is $".$cost.".<br />".
                 "The tax applied is $".$tax.".<br />".
                 "Therefore, the total cost is $".$total.".</h3>";
         return $text;
}

function calculateCost($ramHatQ, $teemoHatQ, $blitzHoodieQ, $galioHoodieQ, $datAsheQ, $graggyIceQ)
{    
         return ($ramHatQ+$teemoHatQ)*14.99+($blitzHoodieQ+$galioHoodieQ)*24.99+($datAsheQ+$graggyIceQ)*19.99;                          
}

function calculateTax($cost)
{
         return $cost*0.075;
}

function calculateTotal($cost, $tax)
{
         return $cost+$tax;
}

function mailSummary($email, $message)
{
         $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
         $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
         $header .= "From: EMAIL\r\n";
         mail($email, "Product Summary from Riot Store Online", $message, $header);
}
?>
```

Here is the processAttire.php file. I commented out the bit on tax exemption since there really is no point getting into that if I can't even get the thing to work as it is!

```
<?php
        include 'attireCalculate.php';

        $message = message($_POST['ramHatQ'], $_POST['teemoHatQ'], $_POST['blitzHoodieQ'], $_POST['galioHoodieQ'], $_POST['datAsheQ'], $_POST['graggyIceQ']);
        echo $message;

        if ($_POST['wantMail'])
        {
          mailSummary ($_POST['email'], $message);
            echo "<h2>A summary has been sent to you via e-mail.</h2>";
        }
/*      
        if ($_POST['taxExemptStatus'])
        {
                calculateCost($ramHatQ, $teemoHatQ, $blitzHoodieQ, $galioHoodieQ,
                   $datAsheQ, $graggyIceQ);
                echo "<h2>Your tax-exempt status has been taken into account. Tax has been deducted from total cost.</h2>";
        }
        else
                calculateTax($totalCost);
*/              

        ?>
```

And here is the XHTML:

```
<form id="attireForm" onsubmit="return validateAttireForm()"
        action="scripts/processAttire.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Headwear</legend> 
        <table id="attireTable" summary="Headwear">
          <tr>
            <td>Rammus Hat</td>
                        <td>$14.99</td>
                        <td><label for="ramHatType">Type: </label></td>
                        <td><select id="ramHatType" name="ramHatType">
                            <option>Original</option>
                            <option>Ninja</option>
                        </select></td>  
            <td><label for="ramHatQ">Quantity: </label></td>
            <td><input id="ramHatQ" type="text" name="ramHatQ" size="1" value="0" /></td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Teemo Hat</td>
                        <td>$14.99</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><label for="teemoHatQ">Quantity: </label></td>
                        <td><input id="teemoHatQ" type="text" name="teemoHatQ" size="1" value="0" /></td>
                    </tr>       
         </table>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Hoodies</legend> 
        <table id="attireTable" summary="Hoodies">
          <tr>
                      <td>Blitzcrank Hoodie</td>
                        <td>$24.99</td>
                        <td><label for="blitzHoodieQ">Quantity: </label></td>
                        <td><input id="blitzHoodieQ" type="text" name="blitzHoodieQ" size="1" value="0" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Galio Hoodie</td>
                        <td>$24.99</td>
                        <td><label for="galioHoodieQ">Quantity: </label></td>
                        <td><input id="galioHoodieQ" type="text" name="galioHoodieQ" size="1" value="0" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>T-Shirts</legend>
                <table id="attireTable" summary="T-Shirts">
                  <tr>
                      <td>"Dat Ashe" T-Shirt</td>
                        <td>$19.99</td>
                        <td><label for="datAsheQ">Quantity: </label></td>
                        <td><input id="datAsheQ" type="text" name="datAsheQ" size="1" value="0" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>"Graggy Ice" T-Shirt</td>
                        <td>$19.99</td>
                        <td><label for="graggyIceQ">Quantity: </label></td>
                        <td><input id="graggyIceQ" type="text" name="graggyIceQ" size="1" value="0" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>            
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Record?</legend>
                <table summary="Record?">
                  <tr>
                      <td><label for="wantMail">Would you like a record sent to you by e-mail? </label></td>
                        <td><input id="wantMail" type="checkbox" name="wantMail" value="yes" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><label for="email">E-mail Address: </label></td>
                        <td><input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="25" /></td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset>
        <legend>Processing</legend> 
        <table summary="Processing">
                  <tr>
                      <td><label for="taxExemptStatus">Do you have tax-exempt status? </label></td>
                        <td><input id="taxExemptStatus" type="checkbox" name="taxExemptStatus" value="yes" /></td>
                    </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" /></td>
            <td><input id="resetAttire" type="reset" value="Reset Selections" /></td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
        </form>
```

And here is the JavaScript file containing validateAttireForm():

```
//attireValidate.js

function validateAttireForm()
{
     var attireFormObj = document.getElementById("attireForm")
     var ramHatQ = attireFormObj.ramHatQ.value;
     var teemoHatQ = attireFormObj.teemoHatQ.value;
     var blitzHoodieQ = attireFormObj.blitzHoodieQ.value;
     var galioHoodieQ = attireFormObj.galioHoodieQ.value;
     var datAsheQ = attireFormObj.datAsheQ.value;
     var graggyIceQ = attireFormObj.graggyIceQ.value;
     var email = attireFormObj.email.value;

     var quantities = new Array(ramHatQ, teemoHatQ, blitzHoodieQ, galioHoodieQ, datAsheQ, graggyIceQ); 

     for (q in quantities)
     {
         quantityOK = validateQuantity(quantities[q]);
     if (quantityOK = false)
         {
         break;
         }
     }

     if (attireFormObj.wantMail.checked)
        emailOK = validateEmail(email);
     else
        emailOK = true;

    return quantityOK && emailOK;
}

function validateQuantity(quantity)
{
    if (isNaN(quantity))
    {
        alert("Error: One or more quantities are abnormal. Please input a number for quantity.")
        return false;
    }

    if (quantity < 0 || quantity > 100)
    {
        alert("Error: Quantity must be in the range 0-100 units.")
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function validateEmail(address)
{
    var p = address.search(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})$/);
    if (p == 0)
        return true;
    else
    {
        alert("Error: Invalid e-mail address.")
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your form is set to rely on the result of a function called `validateAttireForm()` but i don't see this function anywhere in your code. Did you forget to post it? Or did you not define it?

Comment: It's part of a JavaScript file. Would that have any impact on the PHP files?

Comment: Turn php errors on and see what happens. Also, what is `validateAttireForm`?

Comment: Indirectly, yes. Your form cannot submit until `validateAttireForm()` returns `true`. Note that this has nothing to do with PHP per sé. `validateAttireForm()` refers to a javascript function. And of course, if you don't submit the form, `processAttire.php` never comes into play.

Comment: Okay, just added the JavaScript file at the bottom. I should mention that it works properly and notifies the user of all possible errors denoted in the JS file.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. It is difficult to say without proper testing (or rather, debugging) what happens but it is possible that the function cannot successfully validate the input, therefore returns `false` causing your form to not get submitted. But it could as well work fine. Hard to say. Could you describe exactly what happens after you click the `submit` button?

Comment: As long as there isn't a JS error, the page just sits there and does nothing. Whatever the user inputs remains unchanged until the page is refreshed.

Comment: I also tried turning on PHP errors, but the situation is still as I described it above.

Comment: SquareCat you were right. I disabled the JS file and the PHP works just fine. Thanks for your help! Now I just need to figure out what's up with the JS. Or perhaps I can learn how to use JQuery like the person in the Answers section mentioned.

Comment: @Archipater since you can mix vanilla Javascript w/ JQuery line by line in the same code, yes, I highly reccomend it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mixing PHP and Javascript in the submit action of your form, call processAttire.php in the Javascript itself:

```
$.get('scripts/processAttire.php', function(data) {
   eval(data);
});
```

That way you'll have control what order your scripts are executed in. Note: You'll need to use JQuery for this.